# How to make a function assigning a value using assignment operator in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having the following function :

```
function ObjDataSet () {
this.header = "";
this.dataIdx = 0;
this.DataRows = [];
this.CountRow = 0;
}

.... 

ObjDataSet.prototype.NameString = function(argIdx, argName, argValue) {
    var arrObj = this.DataRows[argIdx-1];
    arrObj[argName] = argValue;
    this.DataRows[argIdx-1] = arrObj;
};
```

And I am using this function like this after declaration:

```
var dataSet = new ObjDataSet();    
dataSet.NameString(1, "CUST_KIND",document.searchForm.CUST_KIND.value);
```

But I would like to use this function like this using assignment operator :

```
dataSet.NameString(1, "CUST_KIND") = document.searchForm.CUST_KIND.value;
```

To use assignment operation, How to change "NameString" function?
I don't want to assign a value as a argument of function.

Thank you.

Comment: Your desired code is not valid JavaScript. it won't work as you desire. You are describing how you would like to your to to _look_, but not really identifying your objective for this code. What is your objective (besides code format)?

Comment: The code you want is invalid syntax - it's simply not possible to run no matter your script's architecture. `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

Comment: I am sorry for my unclear description. I have changed my question. Please take a look again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you are asking. The left hand side of an assignment must be a variable or a property of an object. The closest you can do is this:

```
dataSet.NameString(1).CUST_KIND = 'value';
```

Which assumes `dataSet.NameString(1)` returns an object that can have a property assigned to it. Here is a full demo:

```js
var dataSet = setup();

// Log DataRows before and after assigning:

console.log( dataSet.DataRows );
dataSet.NameString(1).CUST_KIND = 'value';
console.log( dataSet.DataRows );


//////
// Prepare dataSet object with `DataRows[0] = {};`

function setup ( ) {
    function ObjDataSet () {
        this.header = "";
        this.dataIdx = 0;
        this.DataRows = [];
        this.CountRow = 0;
    }

    ObjDataSet.prototype.NameString = function(argIdx, argName) {
        return this.DataRows[argIdx-1];
    };

    const dataSet = new ObjDataSet;
    dataSet.DataRows[0] = {};

    return dataSet;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the code you suggested is invalid syntax. - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'CUST_KIND' of undefined"

Comment: @AprilLim That's only the case if you haven't created an object yet, in which case the code you said you're using was broken too. It works if you create an object first to assign the property to, EG: `dataSet.DataRows[0] = {};`

Comment: I created an object even I didn't show here all. I think that's not the problem. dataset object does not have "CUST_KIND" as a property. of course it does not have. And verifying my code is not my question. I want to know the way of making jquery code to assign a value using assignment operator. If possible, I want something like a link having an example. Thanks.

Comment: @AprilLim That's the question that I answered. My answer works... I'll edit it into a runnable snippet.

Comment: @AprilLim Is there a reason you want to be able to do this anyway? What is wrong with `dataSet.NameString(1, "CUST_KIND",document.searchForm.CUST_KIND.value);`?